# IF formula produced an error

Tags: php, phpexcel

I get an error in my PHPExcel export, because i try to get some values with an IF formula.

Here is the part of the Code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('G4', '=IF(F4>0,E4/F4,0');
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('G11', '=IF(F11>0,E11/F11,0)');
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('G18', '=IF(F18>0,E18/F18,0)');
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('G22', '=IF(F22>0,E22/F22,0)');
```

In excel the formula type is:

```
=IF(F11>0;(E11/F11);0)
```

Here the error code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'RECAP!G28 -> RECAP!G4 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured' 
in D:\apache2215\htdocs\gdevise\lib\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:288

#0 D:\apache2215\htdocs\gdevise\lib\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(576): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue()
#1 D:\apache2215\htdocs\gdevise\lib\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5\Worksheet.php(290): PHPExcel_Worksheet->calculateColumnWidths()
#2 D:\apache2215\htdocs\gdevise\lib\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5.php(171): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5_Worksheet->close()
#3 D:\apache2215\htdocs\gdevise\cdd_export_all_nomail.php(985): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('php://output')
#4 {main}
```

thrown in D:\apache2215\htdocs\gdevise\lib\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 288

Somebody an idea

THX in advance

Achillix

Comment: correct first line...$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('G4', '=IF(F4>0,E4/F4,0)');

Comment: I'm tempted to change the code validate formulae when they are entered to a cell, but it'd be too much of an overhead for the Readers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close and check your `parentheses( )` -

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('G4', '=IF(F4>0,E4/F4,0');
```

To

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('G4', '=IF(F4>0,E4/F4,0)' );
```

Comment: `)` should be inside the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

U forgot to close a barcket:

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('G4', '=IF(F4>0,E4/F4,0');
```

Think this will resolve your problem:

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('G4', '=IF(F4>0,E4/F4,0)');
```